# Create a temporary array in PHP to add to a larger array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create a number of arrays to add to a larger array which I will then index two dimensionally (for example my_array[i][j]).

I believe I am having some type of pointing issue... I am iterating through a loop.... at the top of each iteration I instantiate a new array with the same name. When I try and view the output each item in the array appears blank.

Is there a better way for me to instantiate the "temp" arrays to fill the larger (outer) array? Really appreciate any and all help, this community has helped me through so many questions :D

```
$main_array = array();
                                    
for($i = 0; $i < $member_count; $i++)
{
    $temp_array = array();                                                                                        

    //preform SQL query here
    $sql_get_member_transactions = 'some SQL query to go to my DB';
    foreach($sql_get_member_transactions as $row)
    {                                               
        //cannot get array to update here
        array_push($temp_array, $row['amount']);
    }
                                            

    array_push($main_array, $temp_array);
}
```

---

```
#***FULL CODE BELOW***

$club_transactions = array();
                                        
for($i = 0; $i < $member_count; $i++)
{
                                            
    #create an array for each member in the club,
    #add each memeber's array to a larger array once filled with deposit amounts
    #here check if member had a deposit (later we will check ALL transaction types...)
    #if no deposit on that date add a zero to their array

    $temp_member_transactions = array();
                                            
    $temp_member = my_members[$i];                                            

    $sql_member_transactions = "SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE Date >= '$first_t_date' AND Date <= '$last_t_date' AND RelatedClubID = 'THH'";
    $sql_get_member_transactions  = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_member_transactions);
    //here we will get all transactions that lie within the 
    //event-transaction-date-window... in otherwords, the date window
    //in the year where members transactions occured

    foreach($sql_get_member_transactions as $row)
    {                                               
        //we only want to include the transaction amount
        //in the member-specific array if it belongs to that member
        //otherwise see "else" 
        if($row['T_Owner'] == $temp_member)
        {
            $z = $row['T_Amount'];
        }                         
        else
        {
            //set to 0 so that we still account for the transaction date
            $z = 0;
        }                         
                                            
        array_push($temp_member_transactions, $z);
    }
                                            

    array_push($club_transactions, $temp_member_transactions );
```

Comment: If the array is blank, the likely explanation is that the query isn't returning any rows.

Comment: Hey thanks Barmar, I checked the query a few times to make sure it was returning rows... you think there is any other ways to test this? Or another data structure that may make more sense?

Comment: Can you post your actual code instead of just a comment saying that the query goes here.

Comment: `$sql_get_member_transactions` needs to be the result of the query, not a string as you show here.

Comment: @Barmar you got it! please see the full code

Comment: You're doing the same query repeatedly. Why not do it once and save all the values to a single array, then loop through that array repeatedly?

Comment: The comments suggest that there's a single row for each date. Two different members can't have transactions on the same day?

Comment: That said, I still can't see a reason why you're getting empty arrays.

Comment: If you're trying to create an array of transactions for each date, shouldn't the query have `ORDER BY date`?

Comment: What do you see if you put `echo $row['T_Owner'];` in the inner loop?

Comment: @Barmar - SO sorry i found it... $temp_member = my_members[$i]; .... the "my_members" array needed a "$" in front. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should have gotten a warning "Use of undefined constant my_members"